# How to handle following JSON in Retrofit? Gives Error Invalid double?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2, gson

```
{
"id": "297761",
"results": [{
        "id": "58403fa09251417f7400b62a",
        "iso_639_1": "en",
        "iso_3166_1": "US",
        "key": "CmRih_VtVAs",
        "name": "Official Trailer #1",
        "site": "YouTube",
        "size": 1080,
        "type": "Trailer"
   }]
}
```

**Error: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "58403fa09251417f7400b62a"**

Here is the code with I parse it:

```
@SerializedName("id")private String mId;
@SerializedName("iso_639_1")private String mLanguage;
@SerializedName("iso_3166_1")private String mLanguage2;
@SerializedName("key")private String mKey;
@SerializedName("name")private String mName;
@SerializedName("site")private String mSite;
@SerializedName("size")private Integer mSize;
@SerializedName("type")private String mType;

    @Override 
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) 
{ 
    parcel.writeString(mId); 
    parcel.writeString(mLanguage); 
    parcel.writeString(mKey); 
    parcel.writeString(mName); 
    parcel.writeString(mSite); 
    parcel.writeInt(mSize); 
    parcel.writeString(mType); 
}
```

It is Validated shows correct.In Java used Arraylist of SerializedNames to store data all in string format except "size" attribute is integer.

Retrofit method :-

```
  private ArrayList<MovieTrailer> getTrailers(String id) {
    ApiInterface apiService =
            ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<MovieResponse> call = null;
    call = apiService.getMovieTrailers(id,BuildConfig.THE_MOVIE_DB_API_KEY);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MovieResponse> call, Response<MovieResponse> response) {   
         movieTrailers = (ArrayList<MovieTrailer>) response.body().getTrailerResults();
           Log.d(TAG, "server contacted at: " + call.request().url());


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MovieResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            // Log error here since request failed
            Log.d(TAG, "server contacted at: " + call.request().url());
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
        }
    });
    return movieTrailers;
}
```

Comment: Post the code in which you try to parse/use it. Obviusly, that value is not a double

Comment: What correspond to mId?

Comment: Well, check if you are parsing the correct "id", beacuse there are two index called "id", that are different objects

Comment: how to check sir can you describe?

Comment: You should explain what you do. Post the entire workflow, the entire methods (instance the call, make the call, parsers, etcc). Is there a point where you try to parse a "id" index as double?

Comment: You should post more code... The code for your methods to consume your API would be good

Comment: Either there is not enough code to fully understand your workflow, or you are missing to describe the ArrayList on you are trying to get on the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As the retrofit returned whole JSON result for URL**

I used serializable to go through all the values:

```
@SerializedName("id")
private int id;
@SerializedName("results")
private List<MovieTrailerResults> movieTrailerResults;
```

and then in MovieTrailerResults class added the below give variables and it works correctly.

```
@SerializedName("id")private String mId;
@SerializedName("iso_639_1")private String mLanguage;
@SerializedName("iso_3166_1")private String mLanguage2;
@SerializedName("key")private String mKey;
@SerializedName("name")private String mName;
@SerializedName("site")private String mSite;
@SerializedName("size")private Integer mSize;
@SerializedName("type")private String mType;
```